# Encode string in base64 into Shopify

Tags: base64, shopify, encode

How can I encode a string to base 64 in Shopify?

I need to encrypt into base64 the the buyer email ({{customer.email}}) and the order ({{order_name}})

The scope if for adding the trustedbadge*.de button into the email, and they are requesting the fallow url format:

```
www . trustedshops/buyerrating/rate_XFD9974BBC558C007CD46
431D056DF230.html&buyerEmail="[base64 buyerEmail]: "&
shopOrderID=" [base64 Order] "&channel=cmF0ZW5vd2J1dHRvbg"
```

Is there any way to convert those two values in base64?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: link with tech specification of what I try to achive: 
[link]https://www.trustedshops.de/shopbetreiber/integration/bewertungsbutton.html[link]



```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is **not** encryption -- it's known as an encoding.

There is no shopify liquid filter for base64 that I'm aware of, so you'll have to do this in javascript.

Liquid:
HTML:

```html
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.trustedshops/buyerrating/rate_XFD9974BBC558C007CD46431D056DF230.html&buyerEmail=' + encodeURIComponent(btoa({{ order.email | json }})) + '&shopOrderID=' + encodeURIComponent(btoa('{{ order.order_number }}')) + '&channel=cmF0ZW5vd2J1dHRvbg')">
        Open order on trustedshops.com
    </a>
```

And this code just explains the javascript in that *onclick*.

Javascript:

```js
    // The btoa function is the javascript function to encode a string as base64
    // Since base64 encoded strings can't go directly in a url, we then 
    // need to use encodeURIComponent to make it ok to use in a url.
    var encodedEmail = encodeURIComponent(btoa('hello@example.com')); // aGVsbG9AZXhhbXBsZS5jb20%3D
    var encodedOrderId = encodeURIComponent(btoa('1234567890')); // MTIzNDU2Nzg5MA%3D%3D
    // we can now construct the full url
    var url = 'https://www.trustedshops/buyerrating/rate_XFD9974BBC558C007CD46431D056DF230.html&buyerEmail=' + encodedEmail + '&shopOrderID=' + encodedOrderId + '&channel=cmF0ZW5vd2J1dHRvbg';
    // use window.open to open the url in a new tab
    window.open(url);
    // or use window.location.href = url if you'd like it 
    // to be the same tab
```

Comment: Thank you! 
yes, base64 is an encoding..my fault!